# How to use RSpec and FactoryGirl for simple sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I just started using factory_girl and I tried using:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  Here is my code:

```
RSpec.feature "Send a message" do
scenario "Staff can send a message" do
visit "/"

group = Group.create!(name: "Group A")
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
fill_in "Email", with: "staff@example.com"
fill_in "Password", with: "password"
click_button "Sign in"

person = Person.create!(groups: [group], phone_number: "+161655555555")
message = Message.create(body: "Test Message", group_ids: [group.id])
fill_in "Enter a Message:", with: "Test Message"
check "message_group_#{group.id}"
click_button "Send Message"

expect(page).to have_content("Messages on their way!")
expect(page).to_not have_content("Body can't be blank")
expect(page).to_not have_content("Group ids can't be blank")
end
```

Here is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :user do
  email "cam@example.com"
  password "password"
 end
end
```

Simple right? What could be going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". Describe "going wrong". What warnings/errors do you see?

Comment: can you provide us with the error message ?

Comment: The errors are saying that it basically didn't sign user in. So the rest of the test breaks. @druid I did try that but it didn't work.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm not new to Stack Overflow but yes I'll give that a read. I'll admit I left this question sparse but it's only because I thought that would be enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
fill_in "Email", with: user.email
fill_in "Password", with: user.password
```

Also, if you use devise, you can add next lines to `spec/support/warden.rb` and use method `login_as(user)` instead of submitting login form.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers, type: :feature
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers, type: :request

  config.before :suite do
    Warden.test_mode!
  end

  config.after :each do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end
end
```